# Adding unit test to QMake project without moving source to subdir

Tags: qt5, qmake

I have an existing project based on QMake, and would like to add unit tests. The usual way would be to create a `subdirs` project, and move the source directory to a subdir:

```
myproject/
    <source code>

-->

myproject
    myproject.pro   <- new project
    src/
        src.pro     <- old project
        <source code>
    test/
        <unit tests>
```

Is there a way to do it without moving all the source code to a subdirectory? (Don't ask why. There doesn't have to be a technical reason, say there might be political resistance against such a "big change".)

Can you have the `subdirs` project and the regular project in the same directory? Or can you do it without `subdirs`?

Answer (score 0):

"Can you have the subdirs project and the regular project in the same directory?" Not really, no. The nature of subdirs projects require the subdirs projects be in literal subdirectories.

You could certainly do it using some conditional in your .pro file though. For example, simply add a new build configuration to your project settings like `Test`. (Go to the Projects tab, Build Settings, and perhaps `Clone...` your Debug build configuration if that's the intended configuration for your tests).

For that new build configuration, expand the details of your qmake Build Steps and add a DEFINES += INCLUDE_TESTS.

Now, in your .pro file, simply add a section like:

```
contains(DEFINES, INCLUDE_TESTS) {
    SOURCES += #your test sources in the same directory they've always been

    HEADERS += #your test headers in the same directory they've always been

    # and anything else specific to your testing
}
```

Then simply select your new build configuration `Test` to build and run your tests.